# Should Flux mutation logic always be done in the store, or can it be delegated to a class?

Tags: architecture, javascript, clean-code, flux

(I am using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) but the question applies to any Flux architecture.)

I don't have a great understanding of the reasoning behind Flux architecture. I understand that it is nice to have all of the state in one place. I don't have a great understanding of other things though.

My question here is about where, exactly, the mutation logic should be. I get the impression that Flux architecture wants you to do have all of the mutation logic in one place - the store - because it gives you a good separation of concerns. Ie. when you want to know where mutation logic is, you know where to look.

But I find that it is nice to have classes and use instance methods to deal with state change. I think `user.computeAndSetKarma()` looks a lot nicer than `storeHelper.computeAndSetKarmaForUser(user)`. Robert Martin talks about this in his book *Clean Code*:

> A function with two arguments is harder to understand than a monadic
>   function. For example, `writeField(name)` is easier to understand than
>   `writeField(output-Stream, name)`. Though the meaning of both is
>   clear, the first glides past the eye, easily depositing its meaning.
>   The second requires a short pause until we learn to ignore the first
>   parameter. And that, of course, eventually results in problems because
>   we should never ignore any part of code. The parts we ignore are where
>   the bugs will hide.
>
> ...
>
> Dyads aren’t evil, and you will certainly have to write them. However,
>   you should be aware that they come at a cost and should take advantage
>   of what mechanims may be available to you to convert them into monads.
>   For example, you might make the `writeField` method a member of
>   `outputStream` so that you can say `outputStream.writeField(name)`. Or
>   you might make the `outputStream` a member variable of the current class
>   so that you don’t have to pass it. Or you might extract a new class
>   like `FieldWriter` that takes the `outputStream` in its constructor and
>   has a `write` method.

Consider this example ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/adamzerner/pen/yEVYzJ?editors=1010)):

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <table class="table">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Karma</th>
         <th>Compute karma (with logic done in store)</th>
         <th>Compute karma (with logic delegated to user)</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(user, userIndex) in users">
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.karma }}</td>
        <td>
          <button v-on:click="computeKarmaWithLogicDoneInStore(userIndex)">
            Compute
          </button>      
        </td>
        <td>
          <button v-on:click="computeKarmaWithLogicDelegatedToClass(user)">
            Compute
          </button>      
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/vue@2.0.3,vuex@2.0.0"></script>
```

**JS**

```
class User {
  constructor (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.karma = 0;
    this.posts = [];
    this.comments = [];
  };

  computeAndSetNewKarma() {
    let postQualityScore = this._getPostQualityScore();
    let commentQualityScore = this._getCommentQualityScore();
    let activityScore = this._getActivityScore();
    let newKarma = this._getKarma(
      postQualityScore, 
      commentQualityScore, 
      activityScore
    );

    this.karma = newKarma;
  };

  _getPostQualityScore() {
    return 5;
  };
  _getCommentQualityScore() {
    return 10;
  };
  _getActivityScore() {
    return 15;
  };
  _getKarma(postQualityScore, commentQualityScore, activityScore) {
    return postQualityScore + commentQualityScore + activityScore;
  };
}

const storeHelper = {
  getPostQualityScore: function (posts) {
    return 5;
  },
  getCommentQualityScore: function (comments) {
    return 10;
  },
  getActivityScore: function (posts, comments) {
    return 15;
  },
  getKarma: function (postQualityScore, commentQualityScore, activityScore) {
    return postQualityScore + commentQualityScore + activityScore;
  },
};

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    users: [
      new User('Adam'),
      new User('Bob'),
    ],
  },
  mutations: {
    computeKarmaWithLogicDoneInStore: function (state, userIndex) {
      let user = state.users[userIndex];
      let newPostQualityScore = storeHelper.getPostQualityScore(user.posts);
      let newCommentQualityScore = storeHelper.getCommentQualityScore(user.comments);
      let newActivityScore = storeHelper.getActivityScore(user.posts, user.comments);
      let newKarma = storeHelper.getKarma(
        newPostQualityScore, 
        newCommentQualityScore, 
        newActivityScore
      );

      user.karma = newKarma;
    },
    computeKarmaWithLogicDelegatedToClass: function (state, user) {
      user.computeAndSetNewKarma();
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  store: store,
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    users: function () {
      return this.$store.state.users;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    computeKarmaWithLogicDoneInStore: function (userIndex) {
      this.$store.commit('computeKarmaWithLogicDoneInStore', userIndex);
    },
    computeKarmaWithLogicDelegatedToClass: function (user) {
      this.$store.commit('computeKarmaWithLogicDelegatedToClass', user);
    },
  }
});
```

You could perform the logic inside of the mutation, or you could just call `user.computeAndSetNewKarma()` inside of the mutation, delegating the logic to the users instance method. The latter seems preferable to me, but I'm not sure if this violates convention, and I'm not sure if I am thinking about it properly.

Comment: As written, both of your approaches mutate the object in place, and so neither approach follows [Vue's reactivity rules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules), right? (I haven't done Vue, but I have done React, and it looks like Vue follows a similar approach of discouraging in-place mutations.)

Comment: @JoshKelley Vue(x) does let you mutate the object in place while maintaining the reactivity. There are a few caveats to this though, and that's what the link was discussing. Eg. if you have `let person = { name: 'John Doe' };`, you can't do `person.age = 30`, you'd have to either initialize `person.age = null` upfront or do `Vue.set(person, 'age', 30)` if you want `person` to continue to be reactive.